# The executable was signed with invalid entitlements (0xE8008016)

Tags: duplicates, certificate, entitlements

No idea of what is going on!
I have to duplicate an App so I've renamed it, changed the boundle and remaked all the App ID and certificates.
I compile it and it returns "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements. The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016)."

I googled it and only found something about the Entitlements.plist file, but I don't understand what's that and if it is useful: I try to add it to my project but it seems that I can add the value "get-task-allow" because it seems that it is already that, but I don't find it...
In other words it'a mess and I don't know what to do.

Can anybody and advise me?

**Update**: I've refreshed Provisioning Profiles in the Organizer and now it returns a new error and it doesn't compile any more: Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'xxx' can't be found.
Is it better or worst? 
**Update**: I've changed profile, again at the starting point..

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this same issue.  I had an app which I was able to deploy to my iphone (5.0) from xcode. After updating my phone to 5.1 I could no longer deploy to it because my xcode was outdated. After updating xcode to 4.3.2, my phone was available but the attempts to deploy resulted in the "entitlements" error you mentioned.  I solved this by going into my apple developer account and updating my provisioning profile to include my "new" phone. I did this with my iphone plugged into my mac. So apparently upgrading my phone to 5.1 causes it to be a new device as far as the provisioning profile goes.

I'm very very new to iOS development, so may have no idea what I'm talking about, but the series of steps above fixed this error for me.  Hope it helps!

Comment: oh, obviously after updating my provisioning profile in my developer account, I re-downloaded it for use in building with xcode.

Comment: I fixed it by changing in "edit scheme" the build configuration to debug when I had to debug it and to distribution to submit my app. For me it worked.