# iOS: Safe way to store data which gets deleted along with app

Tags: ios

We need to store various data (accesstokens, receipts). In bytes this is relatively small (20000 symbols or so).

We don't want the user to be able to read and tamper this data because we to some extent don't want any smart users to bypass our systems in some way.

We don't want this data to be stored after app is deleted. Therefore keychain seems inappropriate. This is wanted because it seems sensible that the user should get a clean install every time they install the app.

Comment: is it for iphone / ipad?

Comment: you don't want to use NSFileManager? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsfilemanager_class/reference/reference.html also, looks at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16407980/503527

Comment: @user2071152: yes, for iOS 6 and above

Comment: @VoteforNarendraModi I could use NSFileManager, but I'm not entirely sure about how to make it safe without too much fuzz.

Comment: You can store the data in NSLibrary folder of application bundle.

Comment: @user2071152 I'm not asking about how and where to store plain data. In the description I'm asking how to do this in a safe manner where data is encrypted and not too easy to tamper. Just like keychain except for that we need the data to be wiped along with the application if user deletes app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have the data secure you should use Core Data with apples Data Protection on the DB file.

In addition to that you should encrypt the data itself too.

**UPDATE:**

You may want to give this a look for encrypting the data: [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor)

And this for Data Protection: [Data Protection](http://www.michaelprivat.com/?p=31)

Comment: Sounds like a valid way to go. Do you know about any wrappers for doing this in a simple manner? Just like having a wrapper for keychain: https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXKeychain ? Would be awesome