# how to encrypt core data database whenever app isn't running

Tags: core-data, encryption, ios7

I'd like to use Core Data in my application, which contains sensitive information. So I would like to protect it from being accessed, even on phones which aren't locked.

Right now I'm encrypting the sqlite, sqlite-shm and sqlite-wal files in `didEnterBackground:` and decrypt them again in `applicationWillEnterForeground:`. It works as expected, but I don't know if that's the best way to do. E.g. if my application crashes, it won't encrypt the files.

Encrypting and decrypting single entries/columns in the database isn't the best option as well, because then I can't use predicates, right?

So what's the 'state of the art'? Is there a way to have the sqlite file only decrypted whenever the app is opened?

As the app is >= iOS 7, wWould be checking the encrypted/decrypted state periodically (while the app is in the background) an option? But if the user turns of background refresh I'm lost again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `NSFileProtectionComplete` isn't enough for you ([Data Protection / NSFileProtectionComplete - successfully supported through entitlements.plist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734758/data-protection-nsfileprotectioncomplete-successfully-supported-through-enti) goes into pretty good detail), then [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net) looks promising.